# Can't access Struct member inside a class

Tags: c++, class, struct

I have a class. Class has a structure `_tree_branch_m` and a class member function. That structure is a parameter of the member function. Inside the member function, I have an error to access structure members. What is wrong with my structure? The error is `Field 'NodeType'` could not be resolved.

```
class CascadeClassifier{


protected:
    typedef  char   *Set_m;
    typedef  struct _tree_branch_m *Tree_m;
    struct _tree_branch_m
    {
            short   NodeType;   /* 0=leaf 1=branch 2=cut 3=subset */
            short   Leaf;       /* most frequent class at this node */
            float   Items,      /* no of items at this node */
                    *ClassDist, /* class distribution of items */
                    Errors;     /* no of errors at this node */
            short   Tested;     /* attribute referenced in test */
            short   Forks;      /* number of branches at this node */
            float   Cut,        /* threshold for continuous attribute */
                    Lower,      /* lower limit of soft threshold */
                    Upper;      /* upper limit ditto */
            Set_m   *Subset;    /* subsets of discrete values  */
            Tree_m  *Branch;    /* Branch[x] = (sub)tree for outcome x */
    };

    virtual void ClassifyCase(Tree_m subtree, float Weight, float *LowClassSum, float *ClassSum);

};

void CascadeClassifier::ClassifyCase(Tree_m Subtree, float Weight, float *LowClassSum, float *ClassSum)
{
     if ( ! Subtree->NodeType )//error
     {

     }

}
```

Comment: What error exactly? In which line?

Comment: If you use the word error in your question, please be kind enough to include it with the question.

Comment: That's not reproducable, provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please.

Comment: @jogojapan, that doesn't matter because by the time he's in the function parameters, he's already in the namespace of the class.  That only matters for a leading return type (but not a trailing one, which is why they exist.)

Comment: Sorry the error message is added. The error is Field 'NodeType' could not be resolved. Thanks

Comment: @jogojapan; could you show an example?

Comment: OmnipotentEntity just did in the answer. I agree with that answer (+1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example in action:  http://ideone.com/OxaJVj

You're forward declaring the struct at the same time as assigning it to a typedef.  I do not know if this is kosher and I would have to check the standard.  But simply separating these two steps makes it work:

```
typedef  struct _tree_branch_m *Tree_m;
```

to

```
struct _tree_branch_m;
typedef _tree_branch_m *Tree_m;
```

That being said, I would recommend against using leading underscores, because even though you're technically not in violation of the standard, if you were to capitalize the T or put a second _ or move it to the global namespace you'd be in violation of reserved names.

Answer (score 3):

> **3.3.2/6** The point of declaration of a class first declared in an *elaborated-type-specifier* is as follows:
>
> — for a declaration of the form
>
> *class-key attribute-specifier-seq_opt identifier;*
>
> the identifier is declared to be a *class-name* in the scope that
>   contains the declaration, otherwise
>
> — for an *elaborated-type-specifier* of the form
>
> *class-key identifier*
>
> ... the identifier is declared in the smallest namespace or block
>   scope that contains the declaration.

When you write `typedef  struct _tree_branch_m *Tree_m;`, `struct _tree_branch_m` forward-declares a name in the global scope, `::_tree_branch_m`. `Tree_m` is not in any way related to `CascadeClassifier::_tree_branch_m`.

You need to explicitly forward-declare the member struct:

```
class CascadeClassifier{
    struct _tree_branch_m;  // forward delcaration
    typedef _tree_branch_m *Tree_m;
    struct _tree_branch_m {...};
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I was hunting this down in the standard and you saved me the trouble.  So he *was* in violation of the reserved naming rules.  That's very interesting.